# generate_presigned_post url failing due to "No AWSAcesskey was presented"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I'm generating a presigned post using the following code

```py
def generate_pre_signed_upload_url(content_type: str, expiration: int, fields, bucket_name: str, object_name: str):
    try:
        config = Config(signature_version='s3v4')
        s3 = boto3.client("s3", region_name='us-west-2', config=config)
        return s3.generate_presigned_post(
            Bucket=bucket_name,
            Key=object_name,
            Fields=fields,
            ExpiresIn=expiration,
            Conditions=[{"Content-Type": content_type}],
        )
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
```

The response from this is:

```json
{
    "url": "https://sandbox-taxservice-s3bucket-s3bucket6575f0a6-19dl1xpyc3fzo.s3.amazonaws.com/",
    "fields": {
        "key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "x-amz-algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256",
        "x-amz-credential": "xxxxxxxxx",
        "x-amz-date": "xxxxxx",
        "x-amz-security-token": "xxxxxx",
        "policy": "xxxxxxxx",
        "x-amz-signature": "xxxxxxx"
    }
}
```

When I try and use the url/fields in a post request I get a AWSAcessKey error (see below)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>No AWSAccessKey was presented.</Message>
    <RequestId>354BCDQHZ4NB8Y4D</RequestId>
    <HostId>aBM0WkvvrVg9H+Q2H826rHA/bPhxvSGGEg5HKbkxEHwbzybN0p0dhbR4F8np/ovKHJlx9Cwgrgc=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? None of the parameters I change puts an AWSAcessKey in the returning fields.

Comment: _When I try and use the url/fields in a post request_ Show us this code.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. I copied the fields I'm receiving into an HTML provided by boto3 docs https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html Gives the same problem. Anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

The code is now working, was an incorrect request on the other end. Had to make the request

```
r = requests.post(response['url'], data=response['fields'], files=files)
```